# How to save a dynamically created button in android

Tags: android

How to save a dynamically created button in android. My button dissapears when the app is restarted.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome To SO please read [MCVE] , show your code trials and errors you getting

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind dynamically creating buttons is that they won't be created when the app is initially opened and will be created only when required.

If you require the buttons to be created everytime, just call your dynamic button creation code in `onCreate`.

In case you create multiple dynamic buttons, you'll need to store the data associated with the buttons by some means, retrieve the data when the app is opened and then recreate the buttons based on the data.